# Trying to stream live video using gstreamer but video keeps loading on client side

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, streaming, gstreamer, raspbian

I have a raspberry pi 4 which I have a see3cam connected to via USB. I am trying to stream the live video to IP so that a computer on the same network can access the live feed.

I have tested that the camera in fact works with the raspberry pi. I'm able to watch it on the pi itself.

I've been following [this](http://4youngpadawans.com/stream-live-video-to-browser-using-gstreamer/)  tutorial.

My directory is /home/pi/cam, which now contains the multiple segment files, playlist.m3u8, and index.html.

When opening http://123.456.78.910:8080/index.html on another computer the page loads, but once you click play it just keeps loading forever and no video is actually shown. After trying to access the feed from the second computer, the raspberry pi displays

```
123.456.78.910 - - [31/Oct/2022 14:03:18] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
123.456.78.910 - - [31/Oct/2022 14:03:19] "GET /playlist.m3u8 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
123.456.78.910 - - [31/Oct/2022 14:03:26] "GET /playlist.m3u8 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

There are no error messages.
I appreciate any advice, thank you for your time.

In one terminal I ran the following (results included):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/cam $ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! clockoverlay time-format="%D %H:%M:%S" ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink playlist-root=http://123.456.78.910 location=/home/pi/cam/segment_%05d.ts target-duration=5 max-files=5
```

It ran successfully with the message "Setting pipeline to PLAYING..."

In another console I ran (results included):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/cam $ python3 -m http.server 8080
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8080 (http://0.0.0.0:8080/) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As we can see "playlist.m3u8" is called but the segment are not

```
123.456.78.910 - - [31/Oct/2022 14:03:18] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200. -
123.456.78.910 - - [31/Oct/2022 14:03:19] "GET /playlist.m3u8 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
123.456.78.910 - - [31/Oct/2022 14:03:26] "GET /playlist.m3u8 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

This mainly because :
The playlist.m3u8 generated deliver wrong link for ts files

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5

#EXTINF:5.0053420066833496,
http://123.456.78.910/segment_00000.ts
#EXTINF:5,
http://123.456.78.910/segment_00001.ts
```

This command should help :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/cam $ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! clockoverlay time-format="%D %H:%M:%S" ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink playlist-root=http://123.456.78.910:8080 location=/home/pi/cam/segment_%05d.ts target-duration=5 max-files=5
```